# strings parsed as utf-8 in BeautifulSoup4, even when using from_encoding to set correct charset

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using python, requests and beautifulsoup4 to parse /admin/state.xml from an [Icecast](http://icecast.org) server

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get('<host>/admin/state.xml', auth=('u', 'p'))
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml-xml', from_encoding='ISO-8859-1')

mount_point_metadata = []
for mp in soup.find_all('source):
    meta = {}
    meta['mount_point'] = mp.get('mount')[1:]

    try:
        meta['server_name'] = (mp.find('server_name').text)
    except AttributeError, e:
        pass
    mount_point_metadata.append(meta)
```

The code works fine, and retrieves the expected data. However, when I inspect the `mount_point_metadata`-dictionary string with Norwegian characters are having problems, and all values are utf-8:

```
{'mount_point': u'<name redacted>,
 'server_name': u'<redacted> st\xf8rste!}
```

(in this case, `\xf8`, should be the letter `ø`)

Who does this happen, even if when I use `from_encoding='ISO-8859-1` to give BeautifulSoup the correct encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.encode('utf-8')` on the retrieved data. I gues your code would be something like this:

```
meta['mount_point'] = map(lambda s: s.encode("utf-8"), mp.get('mount')[1:])
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The code results in `meta['mount_point']` being a list of chars, and the encoding was still faulty:

    's',
   't',
   '\xc3\xb8',
   'r',
   's',
   't',
   'e',

I could of course wrap the line in `''.join()` to convert the list to a string, but it still doesn't solve the encoding issue: 

    'server_name': '... st\xc3\xb8rste ...'

Comment: Ok then just say:

    `"".join(map(lambda s: s.encode("utf-8"), mp.get('mount')[1:]))`